# What are Captain Hammer's superpowers?

Tags: dr-horrible

Captain Hammer seems to possess a wide *range* of superpowers including mega-strength and the ability to leap great distances.

Have Joss Whedon, Nathan Fillion or any of the other cast/crew provided a definitive list of Hammer's powers?

[image: Captain Hammer wearing a black-shirt with short sleeves, and a yellow chest emblem, and black gloves]

Comment: Well, there is the hammer...

Comment: @Alarion - I was wait for the inevitable jokes.#

Comment: He may be a bit like golden-age Superman, who would regularly acquire new powers for no good reason at the whim of the writers. When Dr Horrible stops the van, Captain Hammer looks at his gloves with mild surprise as though he thinks he's just discovered that he has telekinesis (i.e. that he stopped the van). This is (to me) one of the subtler funny bits in the movie.

Comment: This question should be VTC-hammered just for the sake of humo**u**r.

Comment: Is he the god of hammers?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I've found a number of references that relate to Hammer's powers;*

### On-screen

**Near-invulnerability:**

- He steps in front of a moving truck with no evident fear of injury
- He takes a blast from a "death ray" and appears to only suffer minor pain

**Leaping**

On several occasions he *leaps* from place to place. It's not apparent if he can fly but it appears not

- Onto a moving vehicle
- From a moving vehicle onto the street
- From the street into a side-street (mere seconds later, just in time to save Penny)

**Super Strength**

Hammer performs several acts of super-strength:

- He throws a car at Dr Horrible's head (off-screen but described)
- He lifts Horrible effortlessly
- He punches the electronic gizmo on top of the wonderflonium transport
- He powers the pedalo around the pond at incredible speeds

### Comic canon.

In the [*Dr Horrible* One-shot Comics](https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/16-655/Dr-Horrible-one-shot), we learn a little more about Hammer...

- He was *born* with super-strength:
  [image: comic panels showing Captain Hammer brawling in a bar, and sitting in front of a happy couple]
- His strength is genetic:
  [image: character in a lab coat, with lab glasses, explaining how he's going to make himself stronger with a sample of Hammer's DNA]
- He can leap at least 30 feet into the air (landing heavily, in line with a jump):
  [image: Hammer jumping in front of a perfume commercial board]

---

### Interviews

There have been a couple of interviews that shed light on his powers. Unfortunately, the sources (comic-con quotes and defunct videos) are slightly dubious. **Treat with caution**:

> *"**One of his superpowers is being stupid.** It’s actually quite powerful, his power of stupidity.  I love how he’s so narcissistic, and he doesn’t know how stupid he is. That’s quite a power."* - Nathan Fillion

<sup><sub>reposted from [Iwanttobelieve](https://classfirefly.tumblr.com/post/59675780246/one-of-his-superpowers-is-being-stupid-its) - supposedly a quote from Comic-Con 2012</sub></sup>

and

> *"Combine a basketball player with an excellent vertical, with a forklift, and that's pretty much Captain Hammer. ... And the power of awesomeness!"* - Nathan Fillion
>
> <sup><sub>reposted from [criticalfumble](https://www.criticalfumble.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-13943.html) - supposedly a quote from [this io9 article](https://io9.com/5029818/exclusive-nathan-fillion-explains-captain-hammers-superpowers) and video that (alas) no longer works</sub></sup>

Answer (score 10):

#### Captain Hammer's powers are never fully defined but he possesses a degree of superhuman strength, shown by his ability to leap to the top of a moving van and destroy Horrible's remote control device with his fist.

- Captain Hammer's real superpower is his invulnerability. He survived the exploding Death Ray of Doctor Horrible at point blank range. The explosion drove shrapnel around the room into the walls,

> killing Penny.

- His invulnerability is so great that until he is damaged by the exploding Death Ray, he had never experienced pain. He exclaims "Is this what pain feels like?" He gets up and runs from the building apparently uninjured.
- Hammer seems to get around by leaping from place to place, and is apparently comfortable leaping from moving vehicles without fear of momentum or inertia.
- Despite his invulnerability he is extremely afraid of ducks and has a severe dislike of dirt and the homeless.

[image: Captain Hammer and a redhead girl sitting on a bench, eating some kind of ice cream. Hammer looks at a nearby duck]

- His heroic nature is offset by his crass sexual innuendos, his sense of superiority and his condescension toward the people in the city he supposedly protects.

Comment: http://nathanfillionsbiceps.tumblr.com/post/59837710021/classfirefly-one-of-his-superpowers-is-being

Comment: This seems to be a semi-transcription of an interview Fillion gave. Main link is dead though :-( http://www.criticalfumble.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-13943.html

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that he threw a car at Dr Horrible